# What is "2 counts" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am a teacher in a college. I received a teaching evaluation and wonder what the meaning of this response of the following question:

- (Q) Can you suggest anything that the instructor could do to improve the quality of teaching?
- (A) N/A (2 counts)

I do not understand what it means by 2 counts?

Comment: Two people responded to the question with "N/A". Were there two evaluators?

Comment: There are more than 70 evaluators. The evaluation form was sent out to each individual's email account.

Comment: '... on two counts' means 'in two distinct ways' / 'for two reasons', but it is unreasonable to expect a definitive answer here with so little to go on. The evaluator is the person to ask.

Comment: One possibility is that N/A stands for “not available,” which means the question was not answered, apparently by two people.

Comment: It could also mean that the question is Not Applicable on two counts (ie that there are two reasons why the question is not applicable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Two counts" means that "N/A" applies twice. It's similar to "Two counts of murder" — the criminal charge is applied twice.

There are two possibilities to interpret it:

- It applies to two items within the Question
- The answer was given by two people

Comment: thanks. it makes sense.